# Helper function to normal format in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, format, helper

i am working in arq worker, while testing some code, i was getting like this format

```
JobDef(function=<function helper at 0x7f79b3582f70>, args=(4, 5, 6, 6), kwargs={}, job_try=None, enqueue_time=datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 28, 6, 18, 7, 247000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), score=1646029087247)
```

But I need in normalize format like

```
{'args': (4, 5, 6, 6) or [4, 5, 6, 6],
 'kwargs': {},
 'job_try': None,
 'enqueue_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 28, 6, 18, 7, 247000, 
                 tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) or 2022, 2, 28, 6, 18, 7, 247000-> correct 
                 date and time,
 'score': 1646029087247
}
```

Any pre-defined way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into [arq source code](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/arq/blob/master/arq/jobs.py) and `JobDef` is defined as follows

```
@dataclass
class JobDef:
    function: str
    args: Tuple[Any, ...]
    kwargs: Dict[str, Any]
    job_try: int
    enqueue_time: datetime
    score: Optional[int]
```

therefore you should be able to feed instance of `JobDef` into [`dataclasses.asdict` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) which should return `dict`. Consider following simplified example

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
@dataclass
class SimpleJob:
    args: list
    kwargs: dict
    score: int
somejob = SimpleJob([1,2,3],{},123)
print(somejob)
print(asdict(somejob))
```

output

```
SimpleJob(args=[1, 2, 3], kwargs={}, score=123)
{'args': [1, 2, 3], 'kwargs': {}, 'score': 123}
```